# PANIC: could not write to file "pg_logical/replorigin_checkpoint.tmp": No space left on device

Tags: postgresql, docker

When I start docker-compose I get this message:

```
event_bot-db-1     | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... sh: locale: not found
event_bot-db-1     | 2022-10-02 08:05:59.279 UTC [30] WARNING:  no usable system locales were found
event_bot-db-1     | 2022-10-02 08:06:00.195 UTC [30] FATAL:  could not extend file "base/1/13587": No space left on device
event_bot-db-1     | 2022-10-02 08:06:00.195 UTC [30] HINT:  Check free disk space.
event_bot-db-1     | 2022-10-02 08:06:00.195 UTC [30] CONTEXT:  COPY sql_features, line 714
event_bot-db-1     | 2022-10-02 08:06:00.195 UTC [30] STATEMENT:  COPY information_schema.sql_features   (feature_id, feature_name, sub_feature_id,   sub_feature_name, is_supported, comments)  FROM E'/usr/local/share/postgresql/sql_features.txt';
event_bot-db-1     |    
event_bot-db-1     | 2022-10-02 08:06:00.197 UTC [30] PANIC:  could not write to file "pg_logical/replorigin_checkpoint.tmp": No space left on device
event_bot-db-1     | child process was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
event_bot-db-1     | initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
```

The result of df -h:

```
root@vm1948022:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            460M     0  460M   0% /dev
tmpfs            98M  628K   98M   1% /run
/dev/vda2        39G  6.5G   30G  18% /
tmpfs           489M     0  489M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           489M     0  489M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            98M     0   98M   0% /run/user/0
```

Looks like temp files which created during database initialization was filled all system memory. IDK how to fix it.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "make migrate && python3 -m app"
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    restart: always
  db:
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run `docker system prune` before starting docker compose. That will reclaim a lot of space on your machine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).